# Make Menu Appear to Admin Users Only Inside Listview Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a two menus in a drawer. I want one menu to appear only to users whose role is an admin. I have saved the roles in `SharedPreferences`.

Code:

```
class _DrawerMobileState extends State<DrawerMobile> {

  bool isAdmin = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getName();
  }
    @override
      void initState() {
        getName();
      }
    
  void getName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    myList = prefs.getStringList("roles");
    myList.forEach((w){
     myList.forEach((w){
  if(w == "ROLE_MODERATOR"){
    isAdmin = true;
  }else if(w == "ROLE_ADMIN"){
    // print('not found');
    isAdmin = true;
  }else{
    debugPrint(w);
  }
});



 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(),

          _createDrawerItem(
              icon: Icons.home,
              text: 'Dashboard',
              onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home')),
          _createDrawerItem(
              icon: Icons.timer,
              text: 'Admin Temperature \n Check-in',
              onTap: () =>
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/temperatureadmin')),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }

 Widget _createDrawerItem(
      {IconData icon, String text, GestureTapCallback onTap}) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(icon),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: Text(text),
          )
        ],
      ),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }
```

How can I add a for each loop inside the list widget to only show the `Admin Temperature \n Check-in` menu, to users who are admins only?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to make any widget disappear for certain users is wrap if in a ? :

ie

```
(isNotAdmin)? Container()
            : _createDrawerItem(
              icon: Icons.timer,
              text: 'Admin Temperature \n Check-in',
              onTap: () =>
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/temperatureadmin')),
```

Comment: doesnt disappear for non admin

Comment: what i have done `myList.forEach((w){
      if(w == "ROLE_MODERATOR"){
        isAdmin = true;
      }else if(w == "ROLE_ADMIN"){
        // print('not found');
        isAdmin = true;
      }else{
        debugPrint(w);
      }
    });`

Comment: Let's see all you code. Are you passing in the isAdmin into your widget and are you sure that you have got the value before you draw the widget.

Comment: Your getName is an asyc function but you don't wait for the result before you build the widget. You need a FutureBuilder to wait for isAdmin, so that you can use it in your widget.